# MySQL update table from a EAV table using case when

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, entity-attribute-value, case-when

I have a EAV table. I want to convert this into a normal table in a single query. How can I do this?
Table A

```
| ID | Entity | Attribute |
+----+--------+-----------+
| 1  | AA     | 5         |
| 2  | AA     | 2         |
| 3  | AA     | 4         |
| 1  | BB     | 6         |
| 2  | BB     | 5         |
```

Table B (intended. This has only ID as of now)

```
| ID | AA  | BB   |
+----+-----+------+
| 1  | 5   | 6    |
| 2  | 2   | 5    |
| 3  | 4   | NULL |
```

I tried the following:

```
update B join A using(ID) set b.AA=(case when Entity='AA' then Attribute end),b.BB=(case when Entity='BB' then Attribute end);
update B join A using(ID) set b.AA=(case when Entity='AA' then Attribute else AA end),b.BB=(case when Entity='BB' then Attribute else BB end);
```

But the table is not getting updated. Both the fields are set to NULL for all the IDs. I can write separate update queries for each Entity, but I have >100 different entities and each query takes hours to run (I have many records).

Comment: You only have BB column with nulls?

Comment: This is a sample table. My table has >100 columns. EAV table also has >100 attributes. When there is a missing attribute in EAV table (table A), I want NULL for the corresponding attribute in table B.

Comment: YOur issue is that you need a more restrained CASE,when you JOIN on id for id=1 in table B you get 2 rows in table A.For those 2 rows you get Entity which is once AA and once BB.So you need `case when Entity='AA' AND Attribute =5..` to find the first row